# Getting this really annoying error when reading and putting a String into an array

Tags: java

This is my code to download and read the text in my file in Dropbox. Version is a URL.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(version.openStream()));
String inputLine;
int line = 0;
try{
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        strings[line] = new String(inputLine);
        line++;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Although, I get this really annoying error.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at sky.the.venture.client.Download.getCredits(Download.java:38)
at sky.the.venture.client.LauncherFrame.credits(LauncherFrame.java:315)
at sky.the.venture.client.LauncherFrame.(LauncherFrame.java:49)
at sky.the.venture.Destiny.(Destiny.java:13)
at Start.main(Start.java:11)

So, the part which is an error is Download.java:38. Which is

```
strings[line] = new String(inputLine);
```

So if anyone can help, I will be really happy =D

Comment: Use a List<String> instead of an array, it will grow to whatever length you like.

Comment: Array have not enough space for new elements. Would you like to resize it?

Comment: "really annoying error" - is there any other kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well presumably you only created an array like this:

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
```

Arrays don't resize themselves in Java - indeed, they *can't* be resized. If you want a dynamically sized collection, use a `List<E>` implementation e.g. `ArrayList<E>`:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(inputLine);
}
```

Comment: But then how do I return a list to a String[]?

Comment: Use `lines.ToArray()` to return an array of strings.

Comment: ... if you really need to. Ideally, just work with the list afterwards.

Comment: I'd agree with you Jon, didn't mean to step on your toes there

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are attempting to write to an element of the `strings` array that hasn't been allocated.  For example, if you have allocated something like `strings[10]`, and `lines` is incremented to 11, you will receive the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception.